# Rostopic weird behaviour an Raspberry

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, robot, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

I installed the robot variant on my raspberry Pi. For this I had to get rid of two packages : ros_lisp and collada_urdf. Anyway...

My pi is having a very weird behaviour when publishing on some topic.

Let's say I'm publishing a Twist on the cmd_vel topic like this :

```
rostopic pub -r 1 cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear: {x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}'
```

If I use

```
rostopic echo cmd_vel
```

I'm going to be able to see what is publish ONLY if I start publish before subscribing. If I publish a new message it is not "printed" "detected" until I stop `rostopic echo` and start it again.

This behaviour is global to any subscribe publish since I tried it with another node and I have the same problem.

I have no clue as from where does this problem comes from. If someone got any idea...

EDIT :

after reading this [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/39643/problem-with-roscore-subscription-and-publishing/) I must say that I started a roscore in a terminal by itself so I'm not restarting it.

EDIT 2 :

It might be relevant to say that I'm accessing the Pi through the [Yaler](https://yaler.net/) Interface with ssh. But I'm accessing the Pi so, if I'm not mistaken, everything run on the Pi (I installed ROS through Yaler).

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164636/rostopic-weird-behaviour-an-raspberry/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
Are both of these nodes running on your Pi?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-14**:
Yes both of them are running on the Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I tested again today and it actually work fine...

I have no idea what was happening but my guess is that one of my friend tried to launch a roscore from a ssh session on his computer that didn't work (lots of error messages) and, even though I though it stopped cleanly, it might have not and that would be the reason. At least, this is my guess.

Sorry for the false alert and thanks a lot @ahendrix for an answer that will most certainly be useful in the future !

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like the rostopic echo node isn't receiving the callback from the ROS master that tells it that there's a new publisher, which is probably why it isn't subscribing or seeing any messages.

There are a number of things you can do to debug this.

With just the roscore and the rostopic echo node running, inspect the rostopic echo node. First, find the node name with:

```
rosnode list
```

And look for a node name that starts with `/rostopic`. It will probably be something like `/rostopic_36138_1400087540700`. The inspect the node by running:

```
rosnode info /rostopic_36138_1400087540700
```

If it can't contact the node for some reason, troubleshoot your network configuration and your /etc/hosts file to make sure that the name advertised by the node resolves, either through DNS or through your /etc/hosts file.

If you're running the master on a separate machine from your Pi, also try running `rosnode info` from there, to make sure that the ros master can successfully contact the node to tell it about new publishers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-14**:
It's weird but it seems to be working fine now... I don't know what happen. I'll test tomorrow again, I'll quit it updated !